# What is the difference between the Firebase REST API and SDK clients? And how to the clients work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a couple of questions on Firebase.  I went through their documentation on their site, and the tutorial.  I've never used anything like this before, so it's a bit confusing:

1. I see there is a REST API and a Javascript API.  Is the main difference that the REST API is more like a traditional API and requires polling, whereas the Javascript API allows you to receive deltas from Firebase itself?
2. I want to create a service that receives these deltas and stores them in my own database.  But I don't understand how Firebase can keep a connection open for so long.  I'm assuming there must be a connection open that Firebase pushes the data through back to my service.  Is there a time limit?  Or if the connection gets closed is the best practice to detect this error and re-login?

Comment: One question per post please. That will also allow you to put the gist of the question in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There are many differences between the Firebase REST API and its client libraries. The biggest difference is indeed that most REST clients don't use a persistent connection. But REST clients *can* listen for changes too, using [Firebase's SSE based REST Streaming](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-streaming).
2. Firebase uses web sockets to establish a persistent connection from the client to the server. On browser platforms where web sockets are not available, the client falls back to HTTP long-polling.

Comment: for the web, would we have to write 300kb+ of code to accomplish this in rest? right now, my apps biggest hiccup is waiting for this sdk to come in.